# fgets() won't read content from file to 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, string, fgets

The `fgets`statement is not gathering anything from the `calendarLog` file stream into the `events[][]` array. My `calendarLog.txt` has five lines in it:

```
1/1/1 fds
2/2/2 dsa
3/3/3 sal
4/4/4 444
5/5/5 555
```

The `printf` statement is instructed to output one `!` as well as the `events[counter]`, however, my output statement is only the question marks, `!!!!!`, five of them (if I add more lines to calendarLog, it prints more exclamation points). Why does

```
while(fgets(events[counter++], EVENT_DESCR_SIZE, calendarLog) != NULL)
```

remain true and yet `printf("!%s", events[counter])` not print the `events[counter]`?
All help appreciated!

```
FILE *calendarLog;
char    events[MAX_EVENTS][EVENT_DESCR_SIZE], 
        *newLinePos;
int counter = 0,
    index1,
    index2;    

for (index1 = 0; index1 < MAX_EVENTS; index1++)
    for (index2 = 0; index2 < EVENT_DESCR_SIZE; index2++)
        events[index1][index2] = 0; 
    if ((calendarLog = fopen("calendarLog.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        calendarLog = (fopen("calendarLog.txt", "w"));
        fprintf(calendarLog, "s\n", eventObject);
    }
    else    
    {
        while  (fgets(events[counter++], EVENT_DESCR_SIZE, calendarLog) != NULL) 
        {
            if ((newLinePos = strchr(events[counter], '\n')) != NULL) //takes the '\n' out
                *newLinePos = '\0'; //of the events[counter]
            printf("!%s", events[counter]);
        }
```

Comment: `counter` is index of following the last.

Comment: ohh I need to reposition the'++' thanks

Comment: `fprintf(calendarLog, "s\n", eventObject);` looks like it's supposed to have `"%s\n"` as the format string…

Answer (score 0):

This should tell you everything you need to know about how to fix the problem:

```
FILE *calendarLog;
char  events[MAX_EVENTS][EVENT_DESCR_SIZE];
char *newLinePos;
int   counter = 0;
int   index1;
int   index2;    

// initialize the array: events[][]
for (index1 = 0; index1 < MAX_EVENTS; index1++)
    for (index2 = 0; index2 < EVENT_DESCR_SIZE; index2++)
        events[index1][index2] = 0; 




 if ((calendarLog = fopen("calendarLog.txt", "r")) == NULL)
 { // fopen failed
     calendarLog = (fopen("calendarLog.txt", "w"));
     fprintf(calendarLog, "%s\n", eventObject); // 's' should be '%s
 }

 else    
 { // fopen successful

     while  (fgets(events[counter++], EVENT_DESCR_SIZE, calendarLog) != NULL) 
     {
         // following 'if' is looking at 'next' events because counter is already updated
         // replace '\n' with null to terminate string for following printf
         if ((newLinePos = strchr(events[counter], '\n')) != NULL) 
             *newLinePos = '\0'; 

         // print the value
         printf("!%s", events[counter]);
     }
 }
```